# How does erlang access shared resource?

Tags: erlang

I am a new to erlang, and erlang is concurrency-oriented programming, it has no mutable data structures, that's why it's easy to parallelize.

But anyway, shared resource is still existed, for example, writing to same file. in this case, how does erlang synchronize accessing the shared resource between two processes?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Typically what you might do is have *one* process responsible for access to the shared resource. Other processes would send messages to the single manager process for requests to read or write information to the shared resource.

Some shared resources (eg. some types of ETS tables) can be read by multiple processes but only one process can *write* to it. So you could set up one process to serialise writes to the table but let anybody read from it.

Comment: Also, from my experience, the process responsible to serialize the request is often implemented as a generic server (gen_server): http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/gen_server.html.

Comment: You can have multiple writers to an ETS table. It has a bucket-locking scheme IIRC so it is fairly fast unless different processes write operations collide. A Tuple space is a good analogy for ETS.